# ¿Cómo clasificar una lista obteniendo ciertos índices? (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo una función la cual me recibe como parámetro una lista.

La función hace el proceso de sacarme la longitud de caracteres que posee cada sublista de `lista`, los cuales almacena en la lista `longitudes`.

El resultado que me devuelve dicha función es `[9, 1, 2, 1, 2, 10, 10]`.

Lo que quiero hacer es clasificar esa lista `longitudes` de manera que en otra lista aparte obtener los índices de las longitudes que van de 1 a 3, en otra lista los índices de las longitudes que van de 4 a 9, y en otra lista los índices de las longitudes que van de 10 a 13.

Siendo mas especifico, la primer lista quedaría tipo `lista1= [1,2,3,4]`, la segunda lista seria tipo `lista2=[0]`, y `lista3=[5, 6]`

```
lista = [['letras =1', 'a', ' b', 'c', ' d', ' e letras1', ' letras 5\n']]

def contarLongitudes(lista):
    longitudes = []
    for sublista in lista:
        long_sublist = []
        for elemento in sublista:
            long_sublist.append(len(elemento))
        longitudes.append(long_sublist)
    print(longitudes)
    


contarLongitudes(lista)
```

Sólo he podido hacer la función que me devuelve la cantidad de caracteres de cada sublista.

Me quedo sin poder hacer lo que explico, ya que no tengo mayor idea de como podría hacerlo, agradecería mucho si alguien me pudiera ayudar o guiarme a como podría hacerlo, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para lo que buscas hacer y usando el código que previamente tienes, una solución es usar la función range() que te permitirá acceder tanto como al indice del elemento, como al elemento en sí.

```py
lista = [['letras =1', 'a', ' b', 'c', ' d', ' e letras1', ' letras 5\n']]

def contarLongitudes(lista):
    longitudes = []
    lista1 = []
    lista2 = []
    lista3 = []
    for sublista in lista:
        long_sublist = []
        for elemento in range (0, len(sublista)):
            if 1 <= len(sublista[elemento]) <= 3: #entre 1 a 3
                lista1.append(elemento)
            elif 4 <= len(sublista[elemento]) <= 9:
                lista2.append(elemento)
            elif 10 <= len(sublista[elemento]) <= 13:
                lista3.append(elemento)
            long_sublist.append(len(sublista[elemento]))
        longitudes.append(long_sublist)
    print('longitudes: ', longitudes, '\nlista1: ', lista1)
    print('lista2: ' ,lista2, '\nlista3: ', lista3)    
contarLongitudes(lista)
```

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/range.html

El resultado quedaría así:

```
longitudes:  [[9, 1, 2, 1, 2, 10, 10]]
lista1:  [1, 2, 3, 4]
lista2:  [0]
lista3:  [5, 6]
```

Tal como el resultado que buscas.

Saludos!

Comment: Podrías obtener el indice del elemento y el elemento en si también así: `for indice, elemento in enumerate(sublista)`

Comment: Me sirvió mucho tu ayuda, muchas gracias!